# JQuery Mobile: dynamically loaded page source still available in DOM even after changing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am new to JQuery Mobile and Jquery can any one help me solving the problem.

I have a listview, in that when i click on a link it will dynamically create a page. My problem is when i click on other link in the list view it will create another page and display that page, but the code of page which is created before is still seen in the page source which is displayed by firebug.

this is my html list

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="device_list">
     <li data-icon="delete"><a href="#" data-rel="close">Close menu</a></li>
     <li><a href="#panel-main">Main panel page</a></li>
     <li><a href="#"  id="v1" onclick="open_device_player(v1)></a></li>       
     <li><a href="#"  id="v2" onclick="open_device_player(v2)></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"  id="v3" onclick="open_device_player(v3)></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"  id="v4" onclick="open_device_player(v4)></a></li>
</ul>
```

this is my Jquery function

```
function open_device_player(device_id)   
  {

    var newPage = "<div data-role='page' id='"+device_id+"'><div data-role=header><h1> Device Page </h1></div><div data-role=content><img src='localhost/mjpg/"+device_id+"' width='320'></div></div>";
    $("body").append(newPage);
    $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#"+device_id );

  }
```

Comment: How about to provide a working jsfiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
function open_device_player(device_id)   
{
    var newPage = "<div data-role='page' id='"+device_id+"'><div data-role=header><h1> Device Page </h1></div><div data-role=content><img src='localhost/mjpg/"+device_id+"' width='320'></div></div>";
    $("body").append(newPage);

    $(document).on('pagehide', '#'+device_id,function () {
        $(this).off('pagehide');
        $(this).remove();
    });

    $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#"+device_id );
}
```

This way, when you create your dynamic page you will immediately bind a **pagehide** event to it. When you finally leave dynamically created page it will trigger set **pagehide** event, thus removing page from the DOM and removing bound page event.

Also look at this:

```
$(document).on('pagehide', '#'+device_id,function () {
    $(this).remove();
    $(this).off('pagehide');
});
```

This way of page event binding don't care if page is in the DOM or not. It will trigger as soon as mentioned page is inside the DOM and you are leaving it.

Comment: thank you, you have been very helpful in solving many of my JQM problems.

Comment: I am glad to help :) anytime you need something just post a question and I will help (if it is jQuery/jQuery Mobile related)

Comment: i have some more problem with this code , can we have a chat on this if you free please ....

Comment: Hi, lets do it via mail, my mail is dragan.gaic@gmail.com

Answer (score 2):

jQuery Mobile stores all the pages and also the dynamically loaded pages (with AJAX) in the DOM by default(helps in faster page transitions). Removal of these pages are also done automatically. You need not worry about removing the pages from the DOM manually unless you have a specific requirement.

You can manually remove the page during it's  **`page hide`**  event.

```
$('#pageID').on('pagehide', function () {
   $(this).remove();
});
```

If you want some page to be stored and not removed automatically, you can specify 
**`data-dom-cache="true"`**.

In the latest JQM version  **`pagehide`** event is deprecated so you can use this instead

```
$( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).on( "pagecontainerhide", function( event, ui ) {});
```

Comment: _external_ pages loaded via Ajax are removed once hidden. The code in OP adds page dynamically and not by Ajax.

Comment: @ashok_p You can add it anywhere on the JavaScript file along with the other page load events, but not within any user defined function since it needs to be invoked automatically